# cpu heavy usage linux mint 19 samsung chromebook 3

Tags: linux, laptop, cpu, linux-mint, chromebook

Recently, I installed Linux Mint 19 on my chromebook, and after installation, the cpu usage spikes whenever I interact with essentially any application. I tried uninstalling packages, installing tools, you name it, and still no success. Even surfing the web eats the cpu usage immensely.

please help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now the Q is really vague, have you tried looking at top/htop to see what processes are the busiest? Maybe installing a different window manager / DE might perhaps possibly help (there's a LOT to choose from, I like XFCE, but there's also fluxbox, flwm, IceWM, and a dozen others) but that's just a wild guess. Maybe the web browser (&/or it's extensions/add-ons) are just cpu hogs too.

Comment: My apologies, and yes I used top, but it is not just one process, it's multiple processes that increase and decrease. I also love XFCE desktop, but the task manager is showing somewhat consumption, and i already uninstalled add-ons, extensions, literally anything. I do not know if  Xorg-core relates to XFCE but it is consuming 13% and suddenly drops.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect your issue is the combination of Linux Mint 19 and your Samsung Chromebook 3.

I use Linux Mint on many computers.  When upgrading them from 18.3 to 19, I observed  a *visible* decrease in performance on low end computers. Especially, those that did not have dedicated GPUs. Linux Mint 19 is not a lightweight distribution.  The Cinnamon desktop environment uses a lot of CPU power if you dont have dedicated GPU and video memory.

Your Samsung Chromebook 3 is not a powerful laptop.  It has a 1.6GhHz Intel Celeron CPU and only 4GB of RAM.  There is no dedicated GPU in this system.  The CPU has to do the work of the GPU as well.  Not to mention that the GPU uses system RAM.  There is no dedicated video memory.  These specs are adequate for ChromeOS, but underpowered for a full featured Linux desktop distribution, like Linux Mint.  This is what I believe is causing your spikes in CPU usage when interacting with windows and applications.

If you are set on Mint 19, I would suggest the [Linux Mint Mate](https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=256) edition.  It is not as demanding as the Cinnamon version and should run much smoother on your hardware.  There is a [XFCE](https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=258) version as well.  Personally, I am not a fan of XFCE.  In addition to those, there are large number of [lightweight Linux distros](https://www.google.com/search?q=lightweight%20linux&oq=light&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l3j69i60.1389j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to try, such as [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.com/),

Comment: I mostly agree, but I don't agree on the GPU part. iGPUs are what most Linux users will run their desktops on and what programmers aim for since almost every consumer device has an iGPU. If it doesn't run Wayland, like Nvidia, then I don't care if it's dedicated or integrated. Mobile devices and smartphones also don't have a dedicated GPU but besides niche markets (console gaming, pc gaming, machine learning) that's where most consumers and therefore companies do care about performance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in some parts with Keltari. The low power processors in chromebooks, particularly the Celeron and Pentium ones (modelnumbers including an "N" based on Intel Atom designs) are modern processors but they don't have much headroom. You should not expect a lot of performance and reconsider how you measure performance.

I have a Lenovo N22 with a Celeron and an Asus C302 with an m3. Both run [GalliumOS](https://galliumos.org/) and achieve acceptable results. I even installed KDE Neon on the N22 to test it after some people recommended it and it works fine.

I can use LibreOffce, Gimp, Quadrapassel and the likes without problems. What's more stressing for the CPU are busy websites lazy loading images as you scroll, playing animations (even if it's just a one pixel thin line moving across the screen to give a sense of time remaining when the next item in the carousel is being displayed) or non optimized video content. You may as well look at a [WebGL aquarium](https://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html) all the time. It's stuff keeping these tiny *passive cooled* CPUs busy all the time where they prefer to be idle. I ran aquarium with a lot of details for a month on the N22 to stress it and it had no problems with that though.

If you still think there is something wrong with your installation after testing optimized software start with `dmesg | tail` and `top`.

Further reading: http://www.brendangregg.com/methodology.html

Edit: Also there is [this problem](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/hardware-acceleration-chrome-linux). You Chrome on ChromeOS may be fast with Hardware Acceleration but Chrome on another Linux platform can't enable it and will be slower. You should give Firefox a try in this case.

Comment: I had gallium Os installed on it and updated the distribution from xenial to bionic, and it literally crashed, I don’t know why; it kept kicking me out of my session.  Before I updated I would always type in the command “dmesg”, the same errors would pop up: UNABLE TO LOCATE IOAPIC FOR GSI 183, ERROR PPD STATE MISMATCH. So yes i am set on Linux mint 19 Tara, but it has wine, and virtualbox on it, and I don’t want to delete it to be honest. Can I install Ubuntu mate desktop environment and replace cinnamon environment?

Comment: I ran dmesg tail and this was the results:  27.811892]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
[   27.813725]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port  random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   99.956139] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=5751 end=5752) time 251 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 759, end 771

Comment: That last link might be a bit misleading, looks like it's only talking about some HD video and enabling "VAVDA, VAVEA and VAJDA on linux with VAAPI only" - or is video acceleration the bulk of "hardware acceleration"? Chromium (69) still has a "Use hardware acceleration when available" option, and chrome://gpu has a bunch of things enabled, some websites are visibly different,  I doubt it's all a "false flag". But still good advice to try FF / other browsers too. And easy for OP to try a bunch of different live linuxes too (op, do that)

Comment: @Curiousdemon If you upgraded GalliumOS from version 2 to the 3.0 alpha then it would be best to report this issue to the GalliumOS developers to get feedback. If you did something else that the GalliumOS folks do not recommend then that may be a reason why it's crashing. Regarding your question about desktops: I expect that when you install the respective desktop session package in Ubuntu that everything works, it did for me a while back in VMs when I was DE hopping. I expect the same from Ubuntu derived distros. Gallium should have a more optimized kernel but the choice is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm avoiding galliumos at the moment, because Linux mint mate 19 works wondrous on my chromebook, and it is less annoying to deal with.